# 403 ESPN Error, Account Inactive

Tags: espn

I am trying some basic stuff with espn's API and it doensn't matter what I do, I get this same thing

```
{
  "status": "error",
  "code": 403,
  "message" : "Account Inactive"
}
```

The link I used is

```
http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/baseball/mlb/athletes?apikey=:KEY
```

I have clicked on the link in the email that seemed like it was supposed to activate my account. Any ideas?

I do also have a basic account, although I would guess if I was trying to access something I couldn't, I would get a different error.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I figured it out on accident... I didn't need

```
:KEY
```

but I needed just `KEY` 
with no semicolon..ooops.

I was mistaking ESPNs information on their website. Glad that is clear.